# Knockoutjs star rating css

Tags: css, knockout-3.0, rating-system

I am trying to use Knockout to implement this css star rating which works well http://jsfiddle.net/madannes/r3s1jx4y/:

```
<span class="user-rating">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" /><span class="star"></span>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" /><span class="star"></span>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" /><span class="star"></span>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" /><span class="star"></span>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" /><span class="star"></span>
    </span>
```

I modified it as follows:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Fields">
            <!--ko if: $parent.HiddenElements().indexOf(Name()) == -1 -->
            <!--ko if: Type() == "Stars"-->
            <div data-bind="foreach: Options">
                <span class="user-rating">
                    <input type="radio" name="rating" data-bind="value:  $data.name,checked: $parent.Default" /><span class="star"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <!--/ko-->
            <br />
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
```

The array (which I get from MVC Controller using Ajax):

```
var jsonData  = 
[ {Default: "", Name: "Do you like working here?",Title: "Test Stars",Type: "Stars",
Options:  [
 {name: '1'},{name: '2'},{name: '3'},{name: '4'},{name: '5'}]}];
```

The viewmodel:

```
function FormField(data) {
            var self = this;
            self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
            self.Type = ko.observable(data.Type);
            self.Options = ko.observableArray(data.Type !== 'text' ? data.Options : []);
            self.Default = ko.observable(data.Default);
            if (self.Type() === 'Stars') {
                this.Default.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                    alert(newValue);
                });
            }
        }
        function ViewModel(data) {
            var self = this;
            self.Fields = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (item) {
                return new FormField(item);
            }));
            self.HiddenElements = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.Default = ko.observable();
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(jsonData));
```

It works, except only the star selected is checked for example the third, while in the html/css stars 1,2, and 3 are checked?
I checked the value of each star and they were correct 5,4,3,2, and 1.

Comment: Could you provide your styles for `user-rating`, `star`, and radios? That would help in checking your display problem

Comment: @NickVu http://jsfiddle.net/madannes/r3s1jx4y/

Comment: so you want to have radio values 1,2,3 checked when you select 3, right?

Comment: @NickVu right.  Similar to the jsfiddle example.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are outputting some different html than in the example of the JSfiddle. There´s some magic going on under the hood of the html5 elements in the fiddle you are linking to. Make your html to be just as in the fiddle and add in the styles as well. I'm guessing that the usage of `<fieldset class="rating">` is not random

Comment: thank you but it does not work.  Could you provide a working example.

Comment: I didn't bother to get very into how knockoutjs works, but [here's the working example](https://jsfiddle.net/elissi/b7km20we/)

Comment: Great, I just changed it to <input type="radio"
               name="rating"
               data-bind="attr: {id: 'star' + $data.name }, value: $data.name, checked: $parent.Default" />
        <label data-bind="attr: {for: 'star' + $data.name}"></label>.  The only challenge is using id, this means I can only use one set of stars questions?  any suggestions.  Thanks

Comment: you can reuse it as many times as you'd like. The only thing about it is that the id on the input matches the for attribute on the label. So that they know that they belong together. It doesn't need to be named "star"+number. A good way to name it could be to use the question you have in your jsonData + "star"+ the number. Just something to make it unique enough to not crash with future stuff

Comment: I used  $data.Question + $index() for both label and id, when I select the first question, it works; then if I select the second question, stars are removed from the first question.  I would really appreciate if you could modify your solutions.  Thanks

Comment: can you inspect the input or label element in dev tools and check what `$data.Question + $index()` results in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243874/discussion-between-hncl-and-elissi).